# How to change the column count in "Pages in category x" in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, layout

I have a MediaWiki installation and pages listed on a category, and when I access the category it displays "Pages in category x" and then a 3-column list of pages. What I want is to change the column count to 1 or 2. Is there a way to do this?

Live example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikis (it has 3 columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skimming through [Mediawiki documentation on categories](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Category), it seems you cannot configure the column count. (However, perhaps you could check out the [DynamicPageList](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicPageList_%28third-party%29) extension which has "multi column output", whatever that means...)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself.

There's no setting for this, but I managed to do this by modifying the source code.

The file "includes/CategoryPage.php" has a function "columnList", by changing the two numbers "3" to whatever you want will do it.